# 4K resolution support in Intel AMT

Tags: intel-amt

According to the AMT Reference Guide, the AMT 9.0 supports up to 2K resolution

https://software.intel.com/sites/manageability/AMT_Implementation_and_Reference_Guide/default.htm?turl=WordDocuments%2Fkvmandintelamt.htm

Does the AMT 10 or AMT 11 support 4K resolution?

Thank you.

Comment: You are confused. Intel AMT is Intel Active Management Technology. It is not a GPU.

Comment: I can't find that info either. Have you asked Intel?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, I posted the same question on the Intel Developer Zone  forum, but didn't get an answer yet.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton The document the OP gave a link to clearly describes AMT as supporting some display resolutions.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton: You are confused. Intel AMT includes the ability to  transmit graphics to a remote station as part of the remote desktop feature.

Comment: @LeonidFirdman: Why do you want to know?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Our customer requires this feature. So I want to know if Broadwell (AMT10) or Skylake (AMT11) CPU support it.

Comment: @LeonidFirdman: Your customer is mistaken. Sounds like what they require is OS-specific standard remote desktop software. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

According to the Intel support's answer, the maximum supported resolution of the AMT10 and AMT11 is 2K.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-business-client-software-development/topic/600179#comment-1848093